# How can I make LibreOffice look better?

Tags: themes, libreoffice

For example, this is what LibreOffice Calc looks like right after installation:

[image]

Very Windows 95 looking.

Ho can I make it look more in line with the design of elementary OS?

Comment: The xfce guys working on elementary icons and a theme for libreoffice.
https://github.com/shimmerproject/libreoffice-style-elementary

Comment: @Djax how to install it?

Comment: Try to use WPS Office (Kingsoft) 2016 its very Ms office 2013 feel and look, I luv it.

Comment: Thanks guys, your answers really helped me sort out my tool bar issues with LibreOffice 5. Btw when I had the tango style activated, I noticed my page borders were not complete...anyone else experienced this? I'm currently using the breeze style until this issue is rectified.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You’re missing the `libreoffice-gtk3` package for integration with your GTK+ theme.

Comment: This was it. After doing `sudo apt-get install libreoffice-gtk` now it looks *much* nicer. Thanks!

Comment: Can't this package come with default installation? So newbie users who come to elementary OS specially for the design of it, don't feel any negative feelings when they see the situation at the above.

Comment: GTK3 or gtk+should be used?

Comment: @HimanshuShekhar From LO 5.2 on, I recommend Gtk+ 3.

Comment: Ohh yeah, after installing the GTK package, the look and feel are better. Thank you :)

Comment: In Debian Sid I needed libreoffice-gtk2

Comment: i had to install this and `sudo apt install libreoffice-style-elementary
` then open libreoffice: tools > options > view and change icon style to elementary

Answer (score 11):

There are some style packages available:

```
libreoffice-style-crystal
libreoffice-style-galaxy
libreoffice-style-hicontrast
libreoffice-style-human
libreoffice-style-oxygen
libreoffice-style-sifr
libreoffice-style-tango
```

and probably some more...

I like and use the "breeze-style":
[image]

EDIT: I forgot to mention that I installed LibreOffice via PPA (https://launchpad.net/~libreoffice/+archive/ubuntu/libreoffice-4-4). Gabriel wrote that the "crystal-package" wants to remove other LibreOffice packages. To be sure here is a list of all my libreoffice* packages:

```
libreoffice
libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer
libreoffice-base
libreoffice-base-core
libreoffice-base-drivers
libreoffice-calc
libreoffice-common
libreoffice-core
libreoffice-draw
libreoffice-gnome
libreoffice-gtk
libreoffice-help-de
libreoffice-help-en-gb
libreoffice-help-en-us
libreoffice-impress
libreoffice-java-common
libreoffice-l10n-de
libreoffice-l10n-en-gb
libreoffice-l10n-en-us
libreoffice-math
libreoffice-pdfimport
libreoffice-report-builder-bin
libreoffice-sdbc-firebird
libreoffice-sdbc-hsqldb
libreoffice-style-breeze
libreoffice-style-crystal
libreoffice-style-galaxy
libreoffice-style-human
libreoffice-style-oxygen
libreoffice-style-sifr
libreoffice-writer
```

Comment: Trying to install `libreoffice-style-crystal` wants to remove `libreoffice-base-core libreoffice-calc libreoffice-common libreoffice-core python3-uno` (!?). Installing other packages has no effect on how LibreOffice looks. do I need to change something else *inside* the app?

Comment: Yes, to implement those styles you should go to `Tools` -> `Options` -> `LibreOffice` (dropdown menu) -> `Styles` and change the style.

Comment: You probably mean `View` since there is no `Styles` option. In any case, this only changes the icons, not the overall look of the app. Thank you for all the icon sets though!

Answer (score 4):

To have a more appropriate look, you can install the Sifr icon theme :

```
sudo apt-get install libreoffice-style-sifr
```

After install, open Libreoffice and go to *Tools* → *Options* and select Sifr icons and small size.

I hope you like it.

Comment: I _think_ that `libreoffice-style-sifr` gets installed automatically now.

Comment: This appears to only change the icons used, not the overall theme.

Answer (score 0):

What version of the LibreOffice are you using? This looks like the old version, from the Software Center. To get the newest version:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```